# Project runs in IDE but the JAR file does not execute due to NPE in proxy manager

Tags: java, jar, proxy, nullpointerexception, build-process

The project compiles and runs as expected in the IDE; I am using IntelliJ. In order for it to run in it's current environment, it needs to use the browser's proxy settings.

When I build the project to a Jar file and attempt to run it, I get a null pointer exception. I am trying to understand the following:
- What is the reason for this? Does the JAR file get the wrong class-path configurations?
- How can the null pointer exception be resolved? Would it have to do with the settings or is this a code error?
- How does the project work in the IDE but not the JAR file? I checked the contents and the folder structure appears identical.

Debugging is not effective as I am not able to reproduce this in the IDE, it only occurs when I attempt to run the JAR artifact.

```
//Code to initialize proxy using browser settings
      System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
      System.out.println("detecting proxies");
      ExtendedProxyManager.init();
```

Project properties:
[image]

Link to project code on Github: https://github.com/62696e617279/educatorProductivityToolkit/blob/master/src/com/arcologydesigns/Main.java

Here is a detailed stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.getProxyList(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.select(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.arcologydesigns.Main.main(Main.java:44)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.arcologydesigns.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Manifest content and in Jar:
[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The same manifest you are referencing in your IDE project is also bundle with the jar file?

Comment: @hotzst Yes, I updated the question and added an image of the Jar's manifest.mf and the file's contents.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `DynamicProxyManager.getProxyList` where you get the exception and run it from the IDE, do you reach the breakpoint? I could imagine, that the classpath in the IDE is different than when you execute the jar file standalone.

Comment: In the IDE, yes. How could I check the classpath that the jar uses? It works on a non proxy environment, but when I add the proxy code it does not work on any environment. How could I check the classpath that is being used for the jar? I am using the same build process I used before I added the proxy configuration code, namely I point to the main class.

Comment: Either you have an environment variable `CLASSPATH` defined, you pass it along, when you call the jar file, or it is defined in the Manifest (which it isn't based on the above image)

Comment: Ok, so I have my main class in the manifest but need additional classes declared? What should I declare in the manifest? Prior to the proxy code, I have not had to modify the manifest.